# Get dates of previous 3 months from the current month in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I got a Oracle Sql code where I want the dates.

```
select abc,eff_dt 
from xyz 
where eff_dt between 'a' and 'b'
```

I am looking to get dates from previous 3 months.

1. For example if current date is 5/26/2023 then I want a=02/01/2023 and b=04/30/2023.
2. For example if current date is 6/01/2023 then I want a=03/01/2023 and b=05/31/2023.

Comment: What is the data type of column `eff_dt` in [database] table `xyz`? Is it [DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7690645A-0EE3-46CA-90DE-C96DF5A01F8F)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can truncate the current date to the first day of the month, then use interval arithmetic. Probably you want to use half-open intervals rather than computing the last day of the month (this is usually safer, especially if your dates have a time portion):

```
where eff_dt >= trunc(sysdate, 'mon') - interval '3' month
  and eff_dt <  trunc(sysdate, 'mon')
```

Of course this assumes that `eff_dt` of a `date`-like datatype.